# Keep getting garbled text when there's Latex

Tags: bug, mathjax

Chrome on Macbook Pro 10.11.3. Getting this often. One time it went away with a refresh, it usually doesn't:

[image]

Comment: I also experienced it several times. And now I have have found the workaround, *do not scroll the page up or down, until the loading finishes*.